# CRM 4.0 in C# or .NET

Tags: c#, crm, dynamics-crm-4, microsoft-dynamics

I know this is a stupid question for most of the CRM developers but I'm just a beginner and really want to know more about CRM

Just want to ask if it's possible to construct code using C# in OnLoad/OnChange/OnSave events instead of Javascript.

I know a lot about Javascript but I want to know more on coding CRM using C# and VB.NET

Thank you very much.

Comment: No idea what to answer. You can do anything with c#, you just need to know how...

Comment: Check out [the according MSDN topics on Plug-in development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151086.aspx) - they offer all the information you need to get started.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just want to know how to use C# in CRM. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the OnLoad/OnChange/OnSave events of a Dynamics CRM Form can be customized only with JavaScript, C# code can't be executed for these client-side events.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Does this mean that we can only use C# or .NET in Plugins and Workflows or any extension? Coz most of the sample in retrieve/create/retrievemultiple and other common method found in blogs are in C# so i'm trying to use C# in customizing CRM. Thank you very much.

Comment: yes, C# is for workflows, plugins and other extensions. You can find examples of retrieve/create etc etc also in javascript, add SOAP inside your search for javascript retrieve crm 4.0.